# complex xml read certain elements

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

We are receiving this xml in a string and for the death of me I can not seem to get any of the data out of it. We only need a couple of the values but they are all over the board in depth. In the following xml we are looking to obtain

**ShippingService>Rate**

**Label>FileContents>Contents**

**TrackingId**

I have tried xmldocument, xdocument , linq and seem to get any of the info. We used xdocument and linq in other code and works good because there are multiple seqments to loop over and it is much simpler but not on this xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CreateShipmentResponse xmlns="https://www.example.com">
    <CreateShipmentResult>
        <Shipment>
            <OrderId>123456789</OrderId>
            <Weight>
                <Value>8</Value>
                <Unit>oz</Unit>
            </Weight>
            <Label>
                <FileContents>
                    <Contents>fP1R/6hZ8+/lw4W8uIglTthyg2l8mUfM4752G5NEy6hC...</contents>
                    <FileType>image/png</FileType>
                </FileContents>
                <LabelFormat>PNG</LabelFormat>
                <Dimensions>
                <Width>4.0</Width>
                <Length>6.0</Length>
                <Unit>inches</Unit>
                </Dimensions>
            </Label>
            <ShippingService>
                <CarrierName>USPS</CarrierName>
                <ShippingServiceOptions>
                    <LabelFormat>PNG</LabelFormat>
                    <CarrierWillPickUp>false</CarrierWillPickUp>
                    <DeclaredValue>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                    </DeclaredValue>
                    <DeliveryExperience>DeliveryConfirmationWithoutSignature</DeliveryExperience>
                </ShippingServiceOptions>
                <ShippingServiceId>USPS_PTP_FC</ShippingServiceId>
                <Rate>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>2.77</Amount>
                </Rate>
                <ShippingServiceName>USPS First Class</ShippingServiceName>
            </ShippingService>
            <ShipmentId>a098b57ba5384fa39a32b89674b51714</ShipmentId>
            <TrackingId>9300120111402290737718</TrackingId>
        </Shipment>
    </CreateShipmentResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>f9fed16b076a44818486966ee7efb117</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</CreateShipmentResponse>
```

I must be tired because I feel this is really simple. Thanks for any help

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(strResponseData)
            Dim ns As XNamespace = "https://www.example.com/shipment/2015-06-01"
            Dim shipment As XElement = doc.Descendants(ns + "Shipment").First()

            Shipment.rate = shipment.Element("ShippingService").Element("Rate").Element("Amount").Value
Shipment.rate = shipment.Element(ns + "ShippingService").Element(ns + "Rate").Element(ns + "Amount").Value
```

I also tried this and get the same error

```
Dim doc = XDocument.Load("c:\files\11466778294298624.xml").Descendants(ns + "ShippingService").FirstOrDefault().Element(ns + "Rate")
        Shipment.rate = CType(doc.Element(ns + "Amount"), Decimal)
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: What is the questions? Where is the code you tried? What is the error? SO is no coding service, we help out when someone is stuck.

Comment: Likely `doc.Descendants(ns + "Shipment").First()` will work but it may not be the right thing to do if you happen to have a document with more than one `Shipment` elements.

Comment: Thanks Pawal that got me past the first error now when trying to assign a value from Rate to a variable I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I tried shipment.element two different ways and also loading it right into doc but get the same error. When I hover over shipment I can see Amount just cant seem to grab it.

Comment: Issues solved - Thanks Pawal

Answer (score 0):

Your sample XML doesn't have any namespaces defined, but in the code you are using

> Dim ns As XNamespace = "https://www.example.com/shipment/2015-06-01"

when you are reading the XML.

Remove the namespace and it will work

```
    Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(s)
    Dim shipment As XElement = doc.Descendants("Shipment").First()
```

Also this part of your XML is not correct

```
<Contents>fP1R/6hZ8+/lw4W8uIglTthyg2l8mUfM4752G5NEy6hC...</contents>
```

The closing tag should have capital C `</Contents>`